# Any caveats with casting T[] to IList<T>?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, casting, ienumerable

I am implementing a class that wraps an item array, and to facilitate *LINQ* usage I want the class to implement the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

My first "naive" attempt to implement the class is as follows:

```
public class Foo<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
  private readonly T[] _items;

  public Foo(T[] items) { _items = items; }

  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { return _items.GetEnumerator(); } // ERROR

  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
}
```

However, this will not compile, since the array only implements the `IEnumerable` interface and not `IEnumerable<T>`. Compilation error is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.IEnumerator' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

To overcome this issue, I locally cast my array to an interface that inherits `IEnumerable<T>`, for example `IList<T>`:

```
  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { 
    return ((IList<T>)_items).GetEnumerator();
  }
```

This compiles successfully, and my initial tests also indicate that the class correctly functions as an enumerable collection.

However, the casting approach does not feel entirely satisfactory. Are there any caveats with this approach? Could the issue be solved in a more reliable (type-safe) way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems better to do:

```
return ((IEnumerable<T>)_items).GetEnumerator();
```

as [arrays implement `IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9b9dty7d.aspx):

> [...] this type implements `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`

Your first approach didn't work just because the ambiguity between `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` and `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator`.

The problem why it can't be seen within the IDE is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx):

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, the Array class implements the `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`, `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`, and `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces. The implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and therefore are not visible to the documentation build tools. As a result, the generic interfaces do not appear in the declaration syntax for the Array class, and there are no reference topics for interface members that are accessible only by casting an array to the generic interface type (explicit interface implementations). The key thing to be aware of when you cast an array to one of these interfaces is that members which add, insert, or remove elements throw `NotSupportedException`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I had missed the part that the arrays do implement `IEnumerable<T>` as well.

Comment: `IList<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, as should every .NET collection.  A type cannot implement the former without implementing the latter.

Comment: The Aha! paragraph is apparently found in the *Important* section of the [Array class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.array.aspx). In the IDE I could not see the `IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()` method, hence my incorrect conclusion that `IEnumerable<T>` was not implemented.

Comment: Another important thing to note when casting a `T[]` to an `IList<T>` is that the indexed property setter may safely be used to write into the array anything that was read from it, but may not be safely used to write arbitrary references of type `T`.  A `Cat[]` will implement `IList<Animal>`, and an attempt to store a  reference of type `Animal` which happens to identify a `Cat` will succeed, but trying to store a reference to some other kind of `Animal` will fail.  There's no nice way to test whether an `IList<T>` can accommodate a particular `T`, short of trying it and seeing if it throws.

Answer (score 2):

This is fine, but you could just cast to `IEnumerable<T>` instead, since that is the type which actually defines `GetEnumerator()`.  The biggest problem with casting an array to an `IList<T>` is that many of the mutating methods (`Add`, `Remove`, etc.) will throw exceptions.  Since you are casting in a very limited scope, these issues would not affect you.

Comment: I have previously noticed performance penalties when using `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `IList<T>`. Would you say that this is an incorrect obbservation, or will I generally gain speed by casting to `IList<T>` rather than `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: It makes no difference in this case; the purpose of the cast is to invoke `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()`, which is not publicly visible on array types by default.  Both versions of the code would bind to the same method and return the same type of enumerator.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson "I have previously noticed performance penalties" - now that's interesting. Could you elaborate how exactly did you notice this?

Comment: @BartoszKP Maybe these are just faulty observations, but I have recently benchmarked methods (in LinqPad /o+ mode) with `IEnumerable<T>` and `IList<T>` signatures. From what I have been able to tell the `IList<T>` signed methods are consistently faster.

Comment: Interesting.  You might see a slight performance gain when iterating over, for example, a `List<T>` with `foreach` compared to an `IEnumerable<T>` because `List<T>` (and several other built-in collection types) implement enumerators as structs (value types), and the `foreach` pattern is designed to allow this; it does not strictly bind to the versions of `GetEnumerator()` declared by the `IEnumerable` interfaces.  Once you cast it back to an `IList<T>` interface, though, I wouldn't expect to see a difference in most use cases.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson: IEnumerable<T> will in many circumstances be slower than the more complete IList interface because for many operations, Linq is needed. I.e. to get the length of the List, you'll have to use the linq Count() function, which iterates over the list in O(n). On th IList<T> Interface, this just gets a member, so it's O(0).

Comment: @PMF Actually, AFAIK these methods check the underlying type and use the `O(1)` versions when available.

Comment: @PMF The `Count()` operator still accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`; there is not a separate overload for `IList<T>`.  If the **runtime type** of the collection is a list, then `Count()` will take a fast path that just returns `IList<T>.Count`.  The declared type should not make a difference if the runtime type is a list in both cases.  But if a sequence _isn't_ really a list (e.g., if you called `.Cast<U>()` on a list), _then_ there would be a difference.

Comment: Two good answers, both worthy to become accepted answers. I will accept the other answer because it pointed out a flaw in my reasoning. I hope you are not too disappointed with this decision, @MikeStrobel.

Comment: No worries, Anders :).

Comment: @MikeStrobel: I've done a few experiments after your remarks and posted them further down. You're right that `Count()` is taking shortcuts if possible, but still this hurts performance a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to the original question, but after the above discussion, I made some experiments on loop performance.

Here's a test class. It sets up an array of 10000 ints and then uses different loops to concatenate all ints to a string.

```
[TestFixture]
class LinqPerformanceTest
{
    private List<int> m_intList; 

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        m_intList = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            m_intList.Add(i);
        }
    }

    [Test]
    [Repeat(5000)]
    public void LoopWithForeach()
    {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (int v in m_intList)
        {
            b.Append(v.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
    }

    [Test]
    [Repeat(5000)]
    public void LoopWithFor()
    {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

        for (int j = 0; j < m_intList.Count; j++)
        {
            int v = m_intList[j];
            b.Append(v.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
    }

    [Test]
    [Repeat(5000)]
    public void LoopWithLinq()
    {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

        for (int j = 0; j < m_intList.Count(); j++)
        {
            int v = m_intList.ElementAt(j);
            b.Append(v.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
    }

    [Test]
    [Repeat(100)]
    public void LoopWithLinq2()
    {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

        var myEnumerator = new MyEnumerableWrapper<int>(m_intList);

        for (int j = 0; j < myEnumerator.Count(); j++)
        {
            int v = myEnumerator.ElementAt(j);
            b.Append(v.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
    }

    private class MyEnumerableWrapper<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<T> m_innerEnum;

        public MyEnumerableWrapper(IEnumerable<T> innerEnum)
        {
            m_innerEnum = innerEnum;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return m_innerEnum.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }       
}
```

The first two solutions (`LoopWithForeach()` and `LoopWithFor()`) get around the same timing (about 7 seconds on my computer), with a slight advantage on the foreach loop.

`LoopWithLinq` proves that indeed the Count() and ElementAt() Linq functions use shortcuts where possible. The timing is comparable, but still a bit slower than the first two attempts (about 8 seconds). Although Linq does a shortcut evaluation to find that the underlying object actually is a list and Count() an O(1) operation, this is more expensive because of the additional cast required.

The last implementation, `LoopWithLinq2`, where I purposedly wrote an enumerator that does not support direct indexing, definitely shoots trough the roof. It takes 91 seconds for just 100 iterations, that is more than 500 times slower!

Bottom line: For performance reasons, use as specific an interface you have, when possible. The more generic an interface becomes, the less methods it has to directly access relevant data.